# Скрипт перестает работать, когда открывается игровое окно

Tags: python, pyautogui

Пытаюсь создать скрипт, который будет упрощать некоторую работу в игре. Сам алгоритм я плюс-минус написал, но есть одна неувязокчка - скрипт перестает работать, когда открываю игровое окно. Что мне с этим сделать? Объясните максимально подробно, я туповат!!! И да, есть еще вопросик. Будет ли этот код именно удерживать клавишу, а не просто нажимать многократно?

```
def 

    hold_W (hold_time):
        start = time.time()
        while time.time() - start < hold_time:
            pyautogui.press('f')
```

Comment: Вы start не меняете

Comment: вероятнее всего, игра просто не воспринимает такие "нажатия".

Comment: Нет, я не про функция нажатия, а вообще про сам алгоритм. Только игра разворачивается, то скрипт просто не реализуется. То есть, я разворачиваю через панель задач игру, игра разворачивается, а в ней нет никаких действий. Код работает, до тех пор, пока игра не развернута.

Comment: По сути, это скрипт для прокручивания кодового замка на 4 цифры.

Comment: А зачем мне старт менять? Благодаря тому, что start не меняется, я могу вызвать функцию и передать в нее определенный отрезок времени в течение которого будет выполняться press('f'). Мне не понято только, будет ли считаться это функция, как нажатие и удерживание клавиши или будет считаться, как многократное нажатие.

Comment: В своем случае отказался от pyautogui - тоже не работал в полноэкранных приложениях. Мне помогли win32 - windows, xlib - linux.